# C# UWP BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync stop working

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing a Bluetooth app using UWP framework under Visual Studio 2017. Everything is going well thanks to Microsoft Example (C# SDK Example BluetoothLE well written).

During my fourth day of development, the API `BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync` in the line:

```
bluetoothLeDevice = await 
    BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(bleDeviceToConnect.Id);
```

Is no longer working, neither in my app, neither in the original sample from Microsoft I'm using as example (I don't touch anything on it).

I don't understand as I changed nothing (in my project properties, neither any Windows update on my computer). When I call the function, it just never return.

I tried my Bluetooth object used with some smartphone app, and my hardware is working well.

The call is made in a try but no exception is catch, the function just never return (and I wait some time, I don't even have a timeout).

Have you seen this? Any input on how to solve it?

I'm totaly stuck and can't go ahead as I can't connect at all any object now...

Answer (score 0):

If your code and the example code are having the same problem, the only reasons can be that your device is not available.
It is out of reach or even switched off or already connected.
It can also be that if you are using the deviceManager or deviceWatcher, your OS is providing stale information.
For BluetoothLE the windows deviceManager and watcher are nothing but trouble.

Windows sometimes keeps the pairing information and connection status, even if the device is out of reach or switched off.
Many times you have to remove and and  re-add your device in settings to make it available again or a restart is needed.
To save you from all these troubles, I advise you to use the advertisementWatcher.
If your device is found by the advertisementWatcher you know it is in reach and connectable, and there is no need to add your BLE-device in settings.
If needed I can provide a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen because of COM security (as you may know UWPAPI based on WinRTYY which works above COM). [This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/58da3fdb-a0e1-4161-8af3-778b6839f4e1/bluetooth-bluetoothledevicefromidasync-does-not-complete-on-10015063?forum=wdk) should help.

Answer (score 0):

Hello All and thank you for your help on this. 
I got a shot on an other computer and it works just fine.
I double check this morning and found out that even Widnows can't connect to anything over Bluetooth (I tried with the Bluetooth Speaker I'm usually using).
It was a Driver issue, I don't know how it happens, but my computer Driver just stop working, and I add to reinstall it.